# Regular expression to allow one specific character at a time

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a requirement to allow any digits with only one character (either W or D) at a time with no sequence.

For example: **2w** or **222W** or **2d** or **222D** or **2w5d**

(**not** like **2wd**, **55dw**)

I tried something like this but it's not working

```
[^\\d][w]$.
```

Comment: *but it's not working* is not a valid problem description

Comment: Have a try with [`/\b(?:\d+[wd])+\b/i`](https://regex101.com/r/b7PVPl/2). It's a bit unlcar, what about eg `d2`,`d2w`,`d2w2` all those won't be matched by this pattern, just sequences of (digits followed by `w` or `d`).

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

`/\b(\d+[dw](?![dw]))+\b/ig`

**EDIT:** See the answer by @bobblebubble in comments above for a better option.

See snippet below or here: [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/b7PVPl/5)

```js
const regex = /\b(\d+[dw](?![dw]))+\b/ig;
const str = `2w 55dw 222W 2d 2wd 222D 2w5d`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  document.write(`Found match: ${m[0]}<br>`);
}
```

Comment: I think you can drop the comma inside the character class.

Comment: Good catch @bobblebubble. I have edited the code. Also, I like your regex in the comments above better than mine. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: my regex is based on your idea :) well, we don't know what the opener really needs.

Comment: Thanks much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(\d*w(\dd)*|\d*d(\dw)*)\b
```

Test it live here: https://regex101.com/r/2q9ZDM/1

There may be more elegant ways than the 'w then d' OR 'd then w' but it didn't came to me now, so I'm giving you this anyway, because it works well.

Comment: Thanks much for the response. Its working.

Comment: Can you also provide the code that should not accept this way,
For example: 3w5d (should not accept this)